# Accessing an object of options (used in ngSelect), but returning only a specific value in textBox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In the HTML I have this code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in list" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="openDetail(moduleUid, item.uid)"   style="cursor:pointer;">
<td>  {{form.fields['docName'].options.item["docName"]}} </td>
</tr>


{{form.fields['docName'].options}}** returns this:
{"2256":"New document-czech",
"2360":"Jirka test with ML documents_cz",
"2363":"Test sollicitatiebrief",
"2666":"metro"}

{{item["docName"]}}** returns 2256

{{form.fields['docName'].options.item["docName"]}} doesn't return anything
{{form.fields['docName'].options.2256}} returns "New document-czech"
```

I've tried with parsing it to int in the controller, but still the same.

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{{form.fields['docName'].options[item["docName"]]}}
```

i think it will work

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for the answer, but I already tried that, and then it returns an error:



Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' is unexpected, expecting []] at column null of the expression [form.fields['docName'].options[item["docName"] starting at [form.fields['docName'].options[item["docName"].

Comment: try this..

var str = item["docName"];
{{form.fields['docName'].options[str]}}